# How does a change of measure affect covariance?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose I have the three random variables $X,Y,M$ where $E[M] = 1$ under the measure $P$.
Now, suppose I define a new measure $\widetilde P$ so that $\widetilde E[X] = E[M X]$
and $\widetilde E[Y] = E[M Y]$. If $P$ and $\widetilde P$ are absolutely continuous with
respect to each other, is it possible that $\text{Cov}(X,Y) \neq 0$ while 
$\widetilde{\text{Cov}}(X,Y) = 0$?

($\widetilde{\text{Cov}}$ is covariance under the new measure.)

Comment: is $M$ dependent on $X$ and/or $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

$$\begin{align}\text{Cov}(X,Y)&=E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]\\&=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]\end{align}$$

while

$$\begin{align}
\widetilde{Cov}(X,Y)&=\widetilde{E}[XY]-\widetilde{E}[X]\widetilde{E}[Y]\\
&=E[MXY]-E[MX]E[MY]
\end{align}$$

Assume $\Omega=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$, with $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ disjoint and with the same probability $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=P(A_3)=P(A_4)=\frac{1}{4}$.

Put $X=2\chi_{A_1}-\chi_{A_2}$, $Y=2\chi_{A_3}-\chi_{A_4}$, where $\chi_{A}$ denotes the indicator function of $A$. Then $$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=-P(A_1)^2=-\frac{1}{16}\neq0.$$

Consider $M=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\chi_{A_1}+\chi_{A_2}+\frac{1}{2}\chi_{A_3}+\chi_{A_4}\right)$. We can compute $$E[M]=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}P(A_1)+P(A_2)+\frac{1}{2}P(A_3)+P(A_4)\right)=1$$

Finally, we check that $$\begin{align}\widetilde{\text{Cov}}(X,Y)&=-E[MX]E[MY]\\&=-\frac{4^2}{3^2}E[\chi_{A_1}-\chi_{A_2}]E[\chi_{A_3}-\chi_{A_4}]\\&=-(P(A_1)-P(A_2))(P(A_3)-P(A_4))\\&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the example! And because the space is discrete, it's easy to verify that each measure is absolutely continuous with respect to each other.